# Google maps API v3 markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

Can any one give me an idea on how to zoom your map according to the markers. Actually I have geocoded the addresses and the markers are shown on the map. But they are not centered i.e. I have to drag the map to see the other marker.I want my map to fit bounds using the addresses that I have in my `addresses` array. How this can be done.? My current code for geocoding is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var addresses = new Array();
abc = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
//loc = mydiv.getAttribute("data-addr");
var l = abc.length; 
 for (var i=0; i < l; i++){
    if (abc[i].hasAttribute('name'))
    {   
        addresses.push(""+abc[i].innerHTML+""); //removed single quotes here. see previous code
    }   
}
var len = addresses.length;
var geocoder;
var map;
var add = document.getElementById("addr").value;
window.onload = function init() {

      geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();    
      var add = document.getElementById("address").value;
      var latlng = codeAddress(add);
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
          myOptions);
}

//for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++)
//{
    function codeAddress(add) 
    {
      //var addr = addresses[i];
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address':add }, function(results, status) {

          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);     
          } else {
              alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
    }

    function createMarkers()
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
            (function(addresses){
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresses }, function(results) {
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,//error:results[0] is undefined
                        title: address
                    }); 

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        alert(addresses);
                    });
                });
            })(addresses[i]);
        }
    }
    window.onload = createMarkers;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function where you are creating the markers you can also extend the bounds (with

```
function createMarkers()
{
    //create the bounds for the map
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        (function(addresses){
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresses }, function(results) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker ({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,//error:results[0] is undefined
                    title: address
                }); 

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    alert(addresses);
                });
            });
        })(addresses[i]);

        //extend the bounds with each address
        bounds.extend (addresses[i]);
    }
    //fit to the full list of bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds); 
}
```

If you want to set a maximum zoom level no matter what the actual bounds are you can add this after the map.fitBounds (you can change the level of zoom):

```
var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
if (map.getZoom() > 10) map.setZoom(10); 
  google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
});
```

Comment: You can move the `map.fitBounds(bounds);` line outside of the for loop; you only need to do that once

Comment: @spacebean Hey thanks for your answer.It did change the zooming level,but then only one marker was shown on the map. Then I had to write those 2 lines of code outside the `createMarkers()` and that solved my issue.Thanks!

Comment: @spacebean @duncan Here in my map if the places are too close, then the markers are overlapped by using `map.fitBounds()`.Any suggestion so that my markers can be seen distinctly?

Comment: Duncan is correct, the map.fitBounds only needs to be done once, edited to fix. As for the overlapping, the only fix for that is zoom which is what the fitBounds is setting. I will add some code above for if you want to specifically set a maximum zoom allowed.